# iOS7 UISegmentControl image does not display

Tags: ios, ios7

The code below works well on iOS 6 and below

```
NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"segment1.png"],
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"segment2.png"],
    nil];
```

but on iOS 7 only displays two colors block

[image]

Your comment welcome

Comment: Could you be more specific? What do you do with `itemArray`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ios7, the default treatment for images with a segmented control is to colorise them according to the tint properties of the segmented control. To override this behaviour, use the following code

```
NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"segment1.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal],
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"segment2.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal],
nil];
```

Comment: it is the best way to get full-colorized icons in segments! thanks